# Canvas to image: how to keep proportions

Tags: html, canvas, webcam

This my test code: http://jsfiddle.net/Zx4fg/

Why does the circle look like an oval on the canvas?

I want save snapshot from webcam to an image, but the resulting image does not keep proportions.

My real code is:

```
ctx.drawImage(video,0,0, 300, 150); // 300х150 - with this prop. image 
                                    //from webcam on canvas with true proportions
$('body').append($('<img>').attr('src', canvas.toDataURL()));
```

And I getting like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in canvas styling,  u should set its width and height attribute in HTML. not in CSS

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="2400" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
```

Comment: Fatima, i would have never guessed to try this option. Thank you so much!

Comment: Any idea if this is something that will be fixed. Seems a bit backwards of HTML5 to have to include the dimensions as element attributes.

Comment: @FatimaZohra may you look here pls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239288/html5-crazy-canvas-drawimage-sizing