# HTML5: crazy canvas drawImage sizing

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas, html5-video

I have the next html template:

```
<div className="page">
    <video id="video" autoPlay/>
    <canvas id="canvas"/>
    <div class="btn-wrapper">
        <button onClick={this._takePhoto}>Snap Photo</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is screenshot of my app. At the top you can see `<video>` and at the bottom `<canvas/>` (focus in devtools).

[image]

**Problem:** to draw `<video/>` picture to `<canvas/>` I should use this strange coefficients:

```
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
          context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
          video = document.getElementById('video');
    //QUESTION: why?!
    const widthCoef = 2.1,
          heigthCoef = 3;
    context.drawImage(video, 
                      0, 
                      0, 
                      video.clientWidth * widthCoef, 
                      video.clientHeight * heightCoef, 
                      0, 
                      0, 
                      canvas.clientWidth, 
                      canvas.clientHeight);
```

**Question:** *why I should use coefficients if `<video/>` & `<canvas/>` have the same width/height?*

---

If I do the same but without coefficients, like

```
context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.clientWidth, video.clientHeight, 0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight); //OR
context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.clientWidth, video.clientHeight, 0, 0, video.clientWidth, video.clientHeight); //OR
context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight, 0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight);
```

I get a zoomed picture:

[image]

### UPDATE

My new resizing version:

```
_resizeCanvas() {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
        video = document.getElementById('video');
    const width = +window.getComputedStyle(video, null).getPropertyValue('width').replace('px', ''),
          height = +window.getComputedStyle(video, null).getPropertyValue('height').replace('px', '');
    video.width = width;
    video.height = height;
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
},
```

### UPDATE 2 - add fiddle example

[Here is my fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/g0bqb46u/23/)

Comment: How are you setting the width / height of the canvas ? I bet you are mistaking the pixel width/height of the canvas (accessed through canvas.width/canvas.height), and the display size of the canvas (a ccs property accessed through canvas.style.width / height). The display size streches the canvas. Unless you have a good reason to do so (hi-dpi screen support / pixelated effect ), do not change canvas css w/h, only change canvas w/h.

Comment: @GameAlchemist pls look at my update section at the bottom of the question. Do you mean the same?

Comment: @GameAlchemist after setting `width/height` to the canvas/video directly they stop working

Comment: @OrestHera that code also doesn't work

Comment: @OrestHera I'm testing that in Chrome at my PC

Answer (score 2):

Those magic coefficients correspond to the ratio between the `video` object size and the size of canvas.

Suppose, your `video` size is `(400 x 300)` and you want to show it on the canvas with size `(200 x 150)`. It can be done just by:

```
context.drawImage(video,0,0,200,150);
```

It will resize full `video` to fit the canvas.

However, you are using clipping version of `drawImage()`. The first four coordinate arguments describe clipping parameters. For example in the following case it takes quarter of full `video`:

```
context.drawImage(video,0,0,200,150,0,0,200,150);
```

---

*Edit according to updated question*

The image is clipped, since properties `canvas.clientWidth` and `canvas.clientHeight` are larger than `canvas.width` and `canvas.height`. That happens because of CSS `display: flex;`. To show full image use:

```
context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Comment: no, video and canvas is absolutely the same. Not-cliping version works wrong too

Comment: @Volodymyr I guess that there are also some issues with CSS and camera. I can test it without camera: https://jsfiddle.net/27ad0etm/ and with the last CSS version https://jsfiddle.net/ytLgebvg/35/

Comment: I suppose the issue is that css resize canvas in wrong way, but I also fail to resize it with `canvas.width = ...`

Answer (score 1):

Here are working fiddles for my problem. I haven't time yet to investigate why it didn't work on my app. Will update in near future.

*To make them both work on JSFiddle I added `HTML5-video - autoplay` option, don't know how to do the same on StackOverflow*

1. JS + JQuery https://jsfiddle.net/ytLgebvg/42/
2. React.js https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/18812/

### JS + JQuery

```js
function redraw(canvas) {
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
    context.lineWidth = '5';
    context.strokeRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
  
function resizeCanvas(canvas, width, height) {
    var canvasClWidthBefore = +window.getComputedStyle(canvas, null).getPropertyValue('width').replace('px', ''),
        canvasClHeightBefore = +window.getComputedStyle(canvas, null).getPropertyValue('height').replace('px', '');
    alert('canvas cl before: ' + canvasClWidthBefore + 'x' + canvasClHeightBefore);
    
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    
    var canvasClWidthAfter = +window.getComputedStyle(canvas, null).getPropertyValue('width').replace('px', ''),
        canvasClHeightAfter = +window.getComputedStyle(canvas, null).getPropertyValue('height').replace('px', '');
    alert('canvas cl before: ' + canvasClWidthAfter + 'x' + canvasClHeightAfter);
    
    redraw(canvas);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
     context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
     video = document.getElementById("video"),
     videoObj = { "video": true };
 navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
     video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
     video.play();
 }, function() {});
    
    $('#snap-photo-btn').click(function() {
        const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
              context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
              video = document.getElementById("video");
        $('#canvas').removeClass('photoMode');
        $('#canvas').addClass('editMode');
        $('#video').removeClass('photoMode');
        $('#video').addClass('editMode');
        var videoClWidth = +window.getComputedStyle(video, null).getPropertyValue('width').replace('px', ''),
            videoClHeight = +window.getComputedStyle(video, null).getPropertyValue('height').replace('px', '');       
        
        resizeCanvas(canvas, videoClWidth, videoClHeight);
        
  var canvasWidth = canvas.width,
            canvasHeight = canvas.height;     


            
        alert('canvas: ' + canvasWidth + 'x' + canvasHeight);
        alert('video cl: ' + videoClWidth + 'x' + videoClHeight);
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    });
});
```

```css
.main {
    position: relative;
}

video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
video.photoMode { z-index: 1000; }
video.editMode { z-index: -1000; }

canvas {
    /* position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto; */
}
canvas.photoMode { z-index: -1000; }
canvas.editMode { z-index: 1000; }

.btn-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 2000;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <video class="photoMode" id="video" autoPlay></video>
    <canvas class="photoMode" id="canvas"></canvas>
    <div class="btn-wrapper">
        <button id="snap-photo-btn">Snap Photo</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

### React

```js
var Hello = React.createClass({
    
    getInitialState() {
        return { photoMode: true };
    },

    render: function() {
        const clazz = this.state.photoMode ? 'photoMode' : 'editMode';
        return (
        <div className="main">
      <video className={clazz} id="video" autoPlay></video>
      <canvas className={clazz} id="canvas"></canvas>
      <div className="btn-wrapper">
          <button id="snap-photo-btn" onClick={this._snapPhoto}>Snap Photo</button>
      </div>
  </div>
        );
    },
    
    componentDidMount() {
     var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
     context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
     video = document.getElementById("video"),
     videoObj = { "video": true };
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            video.play();
        }, function() {});
    },
    
    _snapPhoto() {
     const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
              context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
              video = document.getElementById("video");
        var videoClWidth = +window.getComputedStyle(video, null).getPropertyValue('width').replace('px', ''),
            videoClHeight = +window.getComputedStyle(video, null).getPropertyValue('height').replace('px', '');       
        
        this._resizeCanvas(canvas, videoClWidth, videoClHeight);
  var canvasWidth = canvas.width,
            canvasHeight = canvas.height;     
            
        alert('canvas: ' + canvasWidth + 'x' + canvasHeight);
        alert('video cl: ' + videoClWidth + 'x' + videoClHeight);
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        this.setState({photoMode: false});
    },
    
    _resizeCanvas(canvas, width, height) {
        var canvasClWidthBefore = +window.getComputedStyle(canvas, null).getPropertyValue('width').replace('px', ''),
            canvasClHeightBefore = +window.getComputedStyle(canvas, null).getPropertyValue('height').replace('px', '');
        alert('canvas cl before: ' + canvasClWidthBefore + 'x' + canvasClHeightBefore);

        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;

        var canvasClWidthAfter = +window.getComputedStyle(canvas, null).getPropertyValue('width').replace('px', ''),
            canvasClHeightAfter = +window.getComputedStyle(canvas, null).getPropertyValue('height').replace('px', '');
        alert('canvas cl after: ' + canvasClWidthAfter + 'x' + canvasClHeightAfter);

        this._redraw(canvas);
    },
    
    _redraw(canvas) {
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
        context.lineWidth = '5';
        context.strokeRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    }
});
 
ReactDOM.render(
 <Hello />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
.main {
    position: relative;
}

video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
video.photoMode { z-index: 1000; }
video.editMode { z-index: -1000; }

canvas {}
canvas.photoMode { z-index: -1000; }
canvas.editMode { z-index: 1000; }

.btn-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 2000;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration-babel.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing on this, and it seems like the 3rd and 4th parameters, which are the width and height of the area you want to take from the source, are relative to the original size of the media, NOT the size of the element the media is displayed in. So, it's based on the original dimensions of your video, and not the width and height of your video element.

I'm surprised the non-clipping version doesn't work though. It seems like it should if you do:

```
context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight);
```

This should take the full video image and display it at the top left corner of the canvas and over the full width and height of the canvas.

Comment: it also doesn't work, but the zoom become little bit better

Comment: Well, then I guess I would suggest that you stick with your working solution. The behavior you're experiencing is very interesting, but if you have something that works, then that's probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

i faced this issue too in my react app.
My solution - set width and height props on canvas tag.

```
<div className="page">
    <video id="video" autoPlay/>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="360"/>
    <div class="btn-wrapper">
        <button onClick={this._takePhoto}>Snap Photo</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and use video.widht \ video.height to fill the context:

```
let video = document.getElementById("video")
let width = video?.width
let height = video?.height
          
ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
```